# How to add line number for output, prompt for line, then act based on input?

Tags: linux, shell

I wrote a shell script like this:

```
#! /bin/sh
...
ls | grep "android"
...
```

and the output is :

```
android1 
android2
xx_android
...
```

I want to add a number in each file, like this:

```
    1 android1 
    2 android2
    3 XX_android
    ...
    please choose your dir number:
```

and then wait for the user input line number x, the script reads the line number back then process the corresponding dir. How can we do this in shell ? Thanks !

Comment: you can find also answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/10201/how-can-i-prepend-a-line-number-and-tab-to-each-line-of-a-text-file \

Comment: This is just a terrible question. The correct answer to the headline is the highest voted answer... while the real problem the asker had is answered by an incorrect answer to the stated question. I don't see how it can be fixed.

Comment: I recommend using a solution like https://github.com/junegunn/fzf which already has this kind of functionality built in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of implementing the interaction, you can use built-in command `select`.

```
select d in $(find . -type d -name '*android*'); do
    if [ -n "$d" ]; then
        # put your command here
        echo "$d selected"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Interesting:  This question was the top hit for "linux add line numbers to output", and I didn't see how this answer helped me.  The issue is that the question was *actually* an X/Y problem - and you answered the Y (whereas I really *did* need an answer to X).

Comment: I found the real problem after reading the whole question. And solved the problem. I'm sorry the search engine didn't discover that.

Comment: @MartinBonner No, this is an X problem / Y user-error.  X problem was asked (don't skim the question), you're looking for Y problem based on title, this answer answered X.

Answer (score 230):

nl prints line numbers:

```
ls | grep android | nl
```

Comment: wow, I never knew `nl` existed.  that was just what I was looking for.

Comment: On my system, this does not number empty lines (which seems to be irrelevant for the application here). Use `nl -b a` to number all lines.

Comment: @krlmlr: on systems without "nl", one could also use : `grep -n '^'`   #^ always exist even on an empty line, so it numbers every lines. So for the OP: it could be done by  `ls | grep "android" | grep -n '^'`

Comment: nl -nrz -w2 pads numbers with zeroes to final lenght of 2 chars

Answer (score 44):

If you pipe the result into `cat`, you can use the `-n` option to number each line like so:

```
ls | grep "android" | cat -n
```

Comment: I want to read the line number back in shell script, process the corresponding dir in shell, so just print the line number seems not work.

Comment: 'cat -n' is non-standard.  'nl -ba' is more portable

Answer (score 15):

Pass `-n` to `grep`, as follows:

```
ls | grep -n "android"
```

From the `grep` man-page:

> ```
>  -n, --line-number
>         Prefix each line of output with the line number within its input file.
> ```

Comment: sorry, my question is not clear. I want to read the line number back in shell script, process the corresponding dir in shell, so just print the line number seems not work.

Comment: You can store the command output in a variable and process it. E.g.: `RESULT=$(/bin/ls | /usr/bin/grep -n "android")`

Comment: yeah, but i find -n print the original line number dir, not starting from 1, is that possible to make it start from 1 ?

Comment: @YifanZhang: You should update your question to clarify. This might help you get better answers.

Comment: the grep -n is great and added : serves well as stop char for following sed filters. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The other answers on this page actually don't answer the question 100%. They don't show how to let the user interactively choose the file from another script.

The following approach will allow you to do this, as can be seen in the example. Note that the `select_from_list` script was pulled [from this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34226734/26510)

```
$ ls 
android1        android4        android7        mac2            mac5
android2        android5        demo.sh         mac3            mac6
android3        android6        mac1            mac4            mac7

$ ./demo.sh
1) android1  3) android3  5) android5  7) android7
2) android2  4) android4  6) android6  8) Quit
Please select an item: 3
Contents of file selected by user: 2.3 Android 1.5 Cupcake (API 3)
```

Here's the `demo.sh` and the script it uses to select an item from a list, `select_from_list.sh`

### demo.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Ask the user to pick a file, and 
# cat the file contents if they select a file.
OUTPUT=$(\ls | grep android | select_from_list.sh | xargs cat)
STATUS=$? 

# Check if user selected something
if [ $STATUS == 0 ]
then
  echo "Contents of file selected by user: $OUTPUT"
else
  echo "Cancelled!"
fi
```

### select_from_list.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

prompt="Please select an item:"

options=()

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  # Get options from PIPE
  input=$(cat /dev/stdin)
  while read -r line; do
    options+=("$line")
  done <<< "$input"
else
  # Get options from command line
  for var in "$@" 
  do
    options+=("$var") 
  done
fi

# Close stdin
0<&-
# open /dev/tty as stdin
exec 0</dev/tty

PS3="$prompt "
select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit" ; do 
    if (( REPLY == 1 + ${#options[@]} )) ; then
        exit 1

    elif (( REPLY > 0 && REPLY <= ${#options[@]} )) ; then
        break

    else
        echo "Invalid option. Try another one."
    fi
done    
echo $opt
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
line-number=$(ls | grep -n "android" | cut -d: -f 1)
```

I use this in a script to remove sections of my sitemap.xml which I don't want Googlebot to crawl. I search for the URL (which is unique) and then find the line number using the above. Using simple maths the script then calculates the range of numbers required to delete the entire entry in the XML file.

I agree with jweyrich regarding updating your question to get better answers.